# Fail to store data in csv file through scraping

Tags: csv, web-scraping

I try to scraping a webpage and extracting data ,then store all data in a csv file. Before adding ScrapeCallback class and calling it, everything works fine. However, it does not store any type of data except headers in the cvs file after adding the new class. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

```
import re
import urlparse
import urllib2
import time
from datetime import datetime
import robotparser
import Queue
import csv
import lxml.html

class ScrapeCallback:

    # extract and store all data in a csv file
    def __init__( self): 
        self.writer = csv.writer(open('countries.csv', 'w')) 
        self.fields = ('area', 'population', 'iso', 'country', 'capital', 'continent', 'tld', 'currency_code', 'currency_name', 'phone', 'postal_code_format', 'postal_code_regex', 'languages', 'neighbours') 
        self.writer.writerow( self.fields)
    def __call__( self, url, html): 
        if re.search('/view/',url): 
            tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html) 
            row = [] 
            for field in self.fields: 
                row.append(tree.cssselect('table > tr#places_{}__row > td.w2p_fw'.format(field))[0].text_content())
            print row
            self.writer.writerow(row)


def link_crawler(seed_url, link_regex=None, delay=5, max_depth=-1, max_urls=-1, headers=None, user_agent='wswp', proxy=None, num_retries=1, scrape_callback=None):
    """Crawl from the given seed URL following links matched by link_regex
    """
    # the queue of URL's that still need to be crawled
    crawl_queue = [seed_url]
    # the URL's that have been seen and at what depth
    seen = {seed_url: 0}
    # track how many URL's have been downloaded
    num_urls = 0
    rp = get_robots(seed_url)
    throttle = Throttle(delay)
    headers = headers or {}
    if user_agent:
        headers['User-agent'] = user_agent

    while crawl_queue:
        url = crawl_queue.pop()
        depth = seen[url]
        # check url passes robots.txt restrictions
        if rp.can_fetch(user_agent, url):
            throttle.wait(url)
            html = download(url, headers, proxy=proxy, num_retries=num_retries)
            links = []
            if scrape_callback:
                links.extend(scrape_callback(url, html) or [])

            if depth != max_depth:
                # can still crawl further
                if link_regex:
                    # filter for links matching our regular expression
                    links.extend(link for link in get_links(html) if re.match(link_regex, link))

                for link in links:
                    link = normalize(seed_url, link)
                    # check whether already crawled this link
                    if link not in seen:
                        seen[link] = depth + 1
                        # check link is within same domain
                        if same_domain(seed_url, link):
                            # success! add this new link to queue
                            crawl_queue.append(link)

            # check whether have reached downloaded maximum
            num_urls += 1
            if num_urls == max_urls:
                break
        else:
            print 'Blocked by robots.txt:', url


class Throttle:
    """Throttle downloading by sleeping between requests to same domain
    """
    def __init__(self, delay):
        # amount of delay between downloads for each domain
        self.delay = delay
        # timestamp of when a domain was last accessed
        self.domains = {}

    def wait(self, url):
        """Delay if have accessed this domain recently
        """
        domain = urlparse.urlsplit(url).netloc
        last_accessed = self.domains.get(domain)
        if self.delay > 0 and last_accessed is not None:
            sleep_secs = self.delay - (datetime.now() - last_accessed).seconds
            if sleep_secs > 0:
                time.sleep(sleep_secs)
        self.domains[domain] = datetime.now()



def download(url, headers, proxy, num_retries, data=None):
    print 'Downloading:', url
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    if proxy:
        proxy_params = {urlparse.urlparse(url).scheme: proxy}
        opener.add_handler(urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy_params))
    try:
        response = opener.open(request)
        html = response.read()
        code = response.code
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        print 'Download error:', e.reason
        html = ''
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            code = e.code
            if num_retries > 0 and 500 <= code < 600:
                # retry 5XX HTTP errors
                html = download(url, headers, proxy, num_retries-1, data)
        else:
            code = None
    return html


def normalize(seed_url, link):
    """Normalize this URL by removing hash and adding domain
    """
    link, _ = urlparse.urldefrag(link) # remove hash to avoid duplicates
    return urlparse.urljoin(seed_url, link)


def same_domain(url1, url2):
    """Return True if both URL's belong to same domain
    """
    return urlparse.urlparse(url1).netloc == urlparse.urlparse(url2).netloc


def get_robots(url):
    """Initialize robots parser for this domain
    """
    rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    rp.set_url(urlparse.urljoin(url, '/robots.txt'))
    rp.read()
    return rp


def get_links(html):
    """Return a list of links from html 
    """
    # a regular expression to extract all links from the webpage
    webpage_regex = re.compile('<a[^>]+href=["\'](.*?)["\']', re.IGNORECASE)
    # list of all links from the webpage
    return webpage_regex.findall(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # link_crawler('http://example.webscraping.com', '/(index|view)', delay=0, num_retries=1, user_agent='BadCrawler')
    # link_crawler('http://example.webscraping.com', '/(index|view)', delay=0, num_retries=1, max_depth=1, user_agent='GoodCrawler')
    link_crawler('http://example.webscraping.com', '/(index|view)', max_depth =2, scrape_callback = ScrapeCallback())
```

Comment: Could you please narrow down your code to a minimal working example in order to reduce unneeded overhead but reproduce your problem?

Comment: @albert yesterday That is a good tip. When I separate the ScrapeCallback class in a different file, the problem solved. Thank you!